# Time series forecasting with R

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, model-selection

I try to forecast my web visitors on the web site for 10 future days using time series. My time series is daily.  I have used an `auto.arima()` model.  Considering the following values for my models, how should I choose between the `ets()` model and `auto.arima()` models:

```
accuracy(auto.arima)
                   ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE    MAPE MASE      ACF1
Training set 26.84448 877.9984 697.2491 -0.7432541 9.72338  NaN -0.126274

accuracy(ets)
                   ME     RMSE      MAE      MPE     MAPE MASE       ACF1
Training set 10.38619 1039.264 833.8032 -1.01747 11.62925  NaN 0.02922446
```

Comment: How long is your series? Could you show a plot of (part of) it?

Comment: yes i have a daily time series witch contain 365 observation (numbre of vistors daily) of 2014

Comment: Choose the one with the lower error. There is a good guide here: http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/compare.htm

Comment: *Which* error measurement should the OP use? According to some, one model has lower error; according to other metrics shown in the question, the other model has lower error!